# Unable to show multiple interactive plot windows

Tags: python, matplotlib

Recently I have been having a problem with matplotlib when I attempt to produce multiple plots. When executing a script like the following only the first plot is shown.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot()
plt.title('1')
plt.show()

plt.plot()
plt.title('2')
plt.show()
```

Even after closing the (window of the) first plot, the second plot never shows up at all. If I add `plt.savefig()` before `plt.show()` in both cases, it does actually save the plots correctly, it just won't show them.

I have a similar problem when running matplotlib from an interactive python session. After doing `plt.show()`, it shows the plot, but when closing the plot the python session crashes without errors:

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> plt.plot()
[]
>>> plt.show()
>>> %
Desktop %
```

The line `>>> %` appears automatically after closing the plot and then the session immediately breaks.

I have tried running from different python interpreters, reinstalling matplotlib, and creating new environments, but none of those solutions work. I use macOS.

Does anyone have an idea what could cause this and how to solve this?

Comment: This doesn’t appear if you use spyder. Wher do you detect this behaviour, which IDE?

Comment: You said you closed one of the windows. Are you sure the title of that window is 1 and not 2?

Comment: I run scripts from the terminal on mac, zsh. The title is indeed 1 and not 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues.

1. When calling `plt.show()`, matplotlib will show all the figure created up to that point and pause the program. Because you have only created one figure at that time, it is only showing that one. To fix this, only call `plt.show()` once at the end of your plotting section.
2. When you call `plt.plot()` it will create a figure if one does not exist or use the previous one if one does. Because you don't create a new figure between the two calls, they will use the same figure. The consequence of that is `plt.title("2")` will be put on the first figure overwriting the original title. Instead, you need to call `plt.figure()` before each plotting call to create new figures for each of them.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot()
plt.title("1")

plt.figure()
plt.plot()
plt.title("2")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This allows me to show multiple plots, but it doesn't fully solve my problem. In your example, I still have the same problem that after ```plt.show()```, I can no longer show any other plot. E.g. If I add the lines ```plt.figure() plt.plot() plt.title("3") plt.figure() plt.plot() plt.title("4") plt.show()``` Plots 3 and 4 never show up, not even if I close plots 1 and 2.

Comment: So to clarify a bit more; ever since I started using matplotlib, doing ```plt.plot()``` and then ```plt.show()``` shows the plot, even if I don't have ```plt.figure()``` first. This would show a window of the first plot, and the program pauses until I close the window. If there are any other figures that are plotted and shown with ```plt.show()``` after the first one, they would all be shown one after the other. But since a few days ago, any figure that is plotted after the first ```plt.show()``` in the code, will not be shown at all.

Comment: (1) You should add these clarifications to your question. (2) Did you update MacOS recently? Did you update any of your other packages that support matplotlib? (3) You said you tried different interpreters, but your question says you're running it using the terminal. Even using an IDE doesn't work?

Comment: Using an IDE also doesn't solve the problem. It is possible that macOS was updated. The motherboard needed replacement a few days ago. And the all data was restored from a backup. After that the problem started to arise.